# Go SDK update to modify the default installation path

Tags: windows, go, installation, sdk, upgrade

I use `go get golang.org/dl/goxxx` and `goxxx download` to update the go SDK of Windows platform, but it is installed on disk C. how to modify the installation path?

Comment: As far as what I can tell from the [code](https://go.googlesource.com/dl/+/be2bfd84e4cf/internal/version/version.go#421), it is hard-coded to be `%USERPROFILE%/sdk`. it does not seems a good practice to modify `%USERPROFILE%` on windows, so I think the best way to do this is just modify the code obtained in `golang.org/dl/internal/version/main.go`, which is just Go code and is fairly simple.

Comment: Thank you very much, it will solve my question

Answer (score 0):

If you set up the project to use go.mod the the replace directive can alter the path from a remote repo to a local path

See https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-file-replace for full details